# Unable to run TortoiseHg, broken libraries and missing dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, qt, pyqt, mercurial

Im having a hard time running [TortoiseHg](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/index.html) (GUI for mercurial). The `PPA` is seriously outdated and there is no self contained `AppImage` or a `SnapCraft` image.

I have previously asked this question in a wrong place (https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=388980)

For some reasons `Qsci` needs to be recompiled to run some of the `Qt` applications.

I have successfully recompiled `Qsci` (version = QScintilla_gpl-2.10.2.tar.gz) but upon trying to create a python binding it complains (Unable to create the C++ code).

```
$ python configure.py
Configuring QScintilla 2.10.2...
QScintilla 2.10.2 is being used.
The QScintilla .sip files will be installed in /usr/share/sip/PyQt4.
QScintilla will be installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4.
PyQt 4.11.4 is being used.
Qt 4.8.7 is being used.
sip 4.19.6 is being used.
The sip executable is /usr/bin/sip.
QScintilla is being built with 'protected' redefined as 'public'.
The PEP 484 stubs will be installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4.
The QScintilla API file will be installed in /usr/share/qt4/qsci/api/python.
Generating the C++ source for the Qsci module...
Error: Unable to create the C++ code.
```

It happens on the latest version of `KDE Neon` and `Ubuntu MATE` and maybe other distros as well which I haven't tested.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Just curious, which Ubuntu version do you have? Both `tortoisehg` and `mercurial` are packaged and work great with Caja and Nautilus.

Comment: +N0rbert 17.04 and 17.10. The deb package for `tortoisehg` is pretty outdated and unfortunately unmaintained for Linux so Im directly running it from the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recompiling doesn't seem to fix the problem up. For whatever reason it still uses Qt4 rather than Qt5.

Luckily found the pre compiled binary.

`sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5.qsci`

fixed the problem up.

Comment: You should use `sudo apt-get build-dep tortoisehg mercurial` next time.

Comment: +N0rbert I wish all the dependencies are self contained like the way they do in AppImage but nonetheless Im glad it is working now.